# making blinking rectangle in matlab

Tags: matlab

hi everyone I'm trying to write a program in matlab that does show a rectangle in gui and blink it. the speed of blinking is defined as period = 1/ freq

it is a simple but i dont know why it is not working right.

what is want to do is making that rect appear and disappear as freq specified

here is my code and it doesnt show any error

```
figure
% the flashing block on frequency 
t = timer;
set(t, 'executionMode', 'fixedRate');
freq = 10;
period = 1/freq;
set(t, 'Period', 1/freq);
set(t, 'TimerFcn', 'show');
flash = true;
show = rectangle('Position',[0,0,1,1],'FaceColor','w');
hide = rectangle('Position',[0,0,1,1],'FaceColor','black');
while (true);

    % set the background to black
    set (gcf, 'Color', [0 0 0] );

    % drawing the rect box 
    n = plot(show);
    wait = period;
    m = plot(hide);

    set(gca,'xcolor',get(gcf,'color'));
    set(gca,'ycolor',get(gcf,'color'));
    set(gca,'ytick',[]);
    set(gca,'xtick',[]);
    return
end
```

i dont know why it is not working. so can someone explain to me

Comment: "not working" doesn't help us understand what the problem is. Is it drawing a circle instead of a square? It's flashing a pink hippopotamus with puce polkadots? It's crashing your computer? Hacking the pentagon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `n = plot(show)` or `m = plot(hide)` , you are actually trying to plot the number represented by the handles to the rectangle you created, so it's not showing a rectangle but rather a point.

What you can do is define the position of the rectangles before the loop, and simply call the function `rectangle` each time you want to display them. However this is cumbersome as you need to delete each rectangle before displaying the new one.

As noted by @CitizenInsane, a much better way is to assign handles to rectangles before the loop (as you are actually doing) and simply toggle the `Visible` property of each back and forth; The result is the same but more efficient and less cumbersome.

Example:

```
figure

% the flashing block on frequency
t = timer;
set(t, 'executionMode', 'fixedRate');
freq = 10;
period = 1/freq;
set(t, 'Period', 1/freq);
set(t, 'TimerFcn', 'show');
flash = true;

RectPos = [0,0,1,1];

%// Set the visible property to off.
    show = rectangle('Position',RectPos,'FaceColor','w','Visible','off');
    hide = rectangle('Position',RectPos,'FaceColor','k','Visible','off');

% set the background to black
set (gcf, 'Color', [0 0 0] );

while true;

%// Play with the "Visible" property to show/hide the rectangles.
    set(show,'Visible','on')

    pause(period)

    set(show,'Visible','off')
    set(hide,'Visible','on');
    drawnow

    pause(period)

    set(hide,'Visible','off');

    set(gca,'xcolor',get(gcf,'color'));
    set(gca,'ycolor',get(gcf,'color'));
    set(gca,'ytick',[]);
    set(gca,'xtick',[]);

end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Building `Rectangle` with `Visible` property set to `off` before the loop and just playing with `set(rectangle, 'Visible', 'on'); % or 'off'` can be a reasonable optimization to have instead of redrawing rectangles each time.

Comment: Yes you're right of course; I tried to put emphasis on the fact that the OP tried to plot handles instead of actual rectangles. I'll edit my answer thanks.

Comment: Also, was testing meantime, many rectangles were accumulating the way it was done, so it's better to play with visibility property.

Comment: Oops I forgot to paste the code to delete them after display. Anyways I delete the code off the first solution as it's clearly too cumbersome; I just left the explanations and left the code for the `Visible on/off` stuff. Thanks!

Comment: the figure is just keep repeated itself each time i close the window

Comment: That's because the while loop is executed forever because of the `true` condition. You can use a for loop to limit the number of iterations or create a callback for the `CloseRequestFcn` of the figure, which is a bit more complicated. If you want to know how to do it please ask.